# Flutter - Change TextField Autocomplete Position

Tags: flutter, autocomplete, textfield

I'm using Flutter's Autocomplete but I would like to have it display above the TextField. Is this possible?

Here's the base setup:

```
Autocomplete<String>(
     optionsBuilder: (TextEditingValue textEditingValue) {
         if (textEditingValue.text == '') {
             return const Iterable<String>.empty();
         }

         if (textEditingValue.text.contains('...')) {
               return widget.myBloc.names
                   .where((String option) {
               return option.contains(
                    textEditingValue.text.toLowerCase());
               });
          } else {
             return const Iterable<String>.empty();
          }
      },
      onSelected: (String selection) {
         log('selection -> $selection');
      },
      optionsMaxHeight: 40,
      fieldViewBuilder: (context, controller, focusNode,
                              onEditingComplete) {
           return TextField();
      }
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, but you're not gonna like the answer...

In the Flutter library, [on line 367 of the RawAutocomplete implementation](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/33403bd28ee09632d4a08f82d0ed0d8b2490d3c8/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/autocomplete.dart#L367), they hardcoded its alignment to track the bottom left of the `TextField`. I was able to circumvent this only after copying their entire implementation, and doing the following:

1. change line 367 to `targetAnchor: Alignment.topLeft`
2. add parameter `followerAnchor: Alignment.bottomLeft`
3. in your `OptionViewsBuilder` wherever you decide to implement it, [shown here in the material Autocomplete implementation](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/33403bd28ee09632d4a08f82d0ed0d8b2490d3c8/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/autocomplete.dart#L155), change to `alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft`.

Comment: This answer will be useless as soon as the file is touched and line numbers change. You should include the relevant code in your answer. And I'm not familiar with this language but I'm sure there must be some kind of inheritance or extensibility that precludes editing library files.

Comment: Case in point: you've linked to an 18-month old version of the file; that line is currently on [line 427](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/autocomplete.dart#L427), and will change again with every commit to that file.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33603606)

Comment: @miken32 you are correct, didn't think about the links not being fixed. As for the inheritance or extensibility, I guess you could probably `@Override` the method, but you'd still likely want to copy the original implementation

Comment: You should [edit] your question to at least include the code block in question showing your changes, be it the whole method or some reasonable section of it.

Comment: I've published the changes suggested above as a package: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_flipped_autocomplete

Comment: Thanks! this is helpful! and it worked at least for particular situation. Simple.